# When hosting asp.net application on Windows server 2012 using IIS 8 no CSS, Javascript or Jquery works

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

When hosting asp.net application on Windows server 2012 using IIS 8 no CSS, Javascript or Jquery works. I have enabled static content on IIS. Tried on all browsers.

here is how they are referenced in the master page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/Styles/styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this. In the Application pool settings the pool had to be set to 'ApplicationPoolIdentiy' and the site had to be set as 'anonymous Authentication'.